# Visual Basic For Applications: Odd Error '-2147417848 (80010108)' en tiempo de ejecución: Error en el método 'Range' de objeto '_Worksheet'

Tags: excel, vba, methods, range, worksheet

Hi I have tried to find a way to fix this error, and I have not succed on that, I am working with a Excel table in a Sheet named "Inventario" after the code inserts the row, and it starts filling that row this error happens, hope someone already has been through that and knows about how to solve it.

```
Private Sub BU1_Click()
    Dim x As Integer, Ultima_Fila As Integer
    Ultima_Fila = Sheets("Inventario").Range("M3") + 2
    i = 1
    Sheets("Inventario").Range("A" & Ultima_Fila).EntireRow.Insert
    Sheets("Inventario").Range("A" & Ultima_Fila) = Sheets("Inventario").Range("M3")
    Sheets("Inventario").Range("C" & Ultima_Fila) = TB2.Value
    Sheets("Inventario").Range("D" & Ultima_Fila) = TB3.Value
    Sheets("Inventario").Range("E" & Ultima_Fila) = TB1.Value
    Sheets("Inventario").Range("I" & Ultima_Fila) = Mid(TB3.Value, 5, 1)
    Sheets("Inventario").Range("J" & Ultima_Fila) = Mid(TB3.Value, 3, 2)
    i = 0
End Sub
```

Ultima_Fila is a cell that counts =MAX(ALL THE IDENTIFIED ROWS)+2, predicts the number or IDENTIFIER of the elements added to the table, and also the row it should be inserted on, just by adding 2 which is the number of cells above the whole table due to the titles.

Comment: What does `Debug.Print Ultima_Fila` return in the Immediate Window?

Comment: Ultima_Fila now prints 12, it is a cell that counts =MAX(ALL THE IDENTIFIED ROWS)+2, to predict the number IDENTIFIER of the element added to the table, and also the row it should be inserted by adding 2 which is the number of cells above the table.

Comment: Also Debug.Print Ultima_Fila before the first line with error, doesnt show an immediate window

Comment: Ctrl+G to open the Immediate Window in the VBEditor.

Comment: Oh it appear also 12

Comment: What specific line is highlighted when you click Debug?

Comment: Sheets("Inventario").Range("A" & Ultima_Fila) = Sheets("Inventario").Range("M3"), however if I remove the instruction, the same error occurs for the next until the last one.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, so there's something else going on here which we can't see...  When it fails and you're in Debug mode, hover over `Ultima_Fila`  - what's the value?  Any merged cells or protection on the sheet?

Comment: Oh I see, with that in mind, I tried running on other computer, and the error is gone, however I still don't know how come my other computer falls in that error.

Comment: Have you tried declaring "Ultima_Fila" in a different way? I recommend you "Ultima_Fila = Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Row + 2" The 13 in the variable means Column M and it returns the last row identified plus 2.

Comment: @DavidDonayo I have tried that too, for know I figured out that If I extend directly the table one more row ahead, the error is not triggered, however it is not practical to have an extra empty row, when the  `Sheets("Inventario").Range("A" & Ultima_Fila).EntireRow.Insert` is in charge to do that.